# Replace Mcrypt with OpenSSL - is that possible

Tags: php, mcrypt

currently we have a mcrypt implentation on our systems to crypt some Ids in our PHP application.
But Mcrypt is deprecated now and I have to replace it.

Unfortunately, I cannot convert all of the saved information.
Decryption would be enough.

These are the two functions that I use:

```
self::$key = '123456';

public static function encrypt($plaintext)
{
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('cast-256', '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::$key, $iv);

    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    $encoded_64 = base64_encode($encrypted_data);

    return trim($encoded_64);
}
```

and

```
public static function decrypt($crypttext)
{
    $decoded_64 = base64_decode($crypttext);

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('cast-256', '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, self::$key, $iv);

    $decrypted_data = mdecrypt_generic($td, $decoded_64);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return trim($decrypted_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Eh?*  PHP has OpenSSL support ... https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

"So, certainly yes."  You can use mcrypt to decrypt all of your existing information and then encrypt it using OpenSSL or some other cipher algorithm of your choosing.

Now, I'd bear in mind that *OpenSSL* is very much designed around the notion of "public and private keys."  So, if you go that route, you should try to take advantage of that.  There are actually a great many cipher algorithms that can be used in modern PHP ... https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php